# MVC4/Razor with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i try to show a googlemaps map in my mvc4 partial view. It worked if i hardcode the latitude and longitude in the javascript - but i want to make it more dynamically. So i tried to replace the long and lat with variables. But i only got a grey googlemaps view. Here is my code. What is wrong? Can anyone help me to fix this?

```
<br />
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;">
</div>

@{
var lat = 6.9167;
var lng = 79.8473;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();
});
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng('@lat', '@lng'),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
<br />
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;">
</div>

@{
var lat = "6.9167";
var lng = "79.8473";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();
});
function initialize(lat, lng) {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(@lat, @lng),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);
}
</script>
```

**Edited**

If latitude and longitude values are stored as double into variables or properties, you should pay attention to the string convertion because of the culture format problem.

I think that the best solution is to use the `ToString("0.#####", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))` method, as:

```
var lat = Model.latitude.ToString("0.#####", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
```

Comment: Okay, this works fine -thanks. BUT how can I do it with a variable from my model / controller? If i try this: @{
var lat = Model.latitude;var lng = Model.longitude;
} I get a white area instead of my map